# how to view ros package code?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to read code for some packages which come with ROS full desktop installation, like robot_state_publisher or turtlesim_node for example. However when I do roscd to reach the directory, I can't find the actual python scripts or cpp files.
How to view the code for these ROS packages? Please help.

I'm using ROS Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319377/how-to-view-ros-package-code?/) by [parzival](https://answers.ros.org/users/35453/parzival/) on ROS Answers with karma: 463 on 2019-03-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-03-25**:
It depends on exactly which package you're referring to, but many ROS packages are found on GitHub. Have you tried searching there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turns out there's a very simple solution.
Just go to the wiki page of that package and clone it to your catkin workspace and build it.

---

Originally posted by [parzival](https://answers.ros.org/users/35453/parzival/) with karma: 463 on 2019-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-25**:
Please note that this is a duplicate of at least #q214020, #q295677, #q214020 and many more.

@parzival: could you please try to use the search (or Google: `source of package site:answers.ros.org`) in the future?